# How to create dynamic button in android as width to view in android

Tags: android, button, view

I have a view, where main heading and its associated sub heading but i don't know length of  string, so, i want to create button based on length of string and if not capable on same line then display next line like a picture.

[image]

Could you please suggest me, how to display such button and its heading in textview or button in android, because i am new, it sucks me since 1 day, i couldnot get any solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using FolowLayout. Refer the following link for details
[FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Answer (score 0):

Please check bellow code for creating textview and a button dynamically and show button below to textview. I think it's helpful to you.

```
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);


    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("My Text fgfdgd fdgdfg dgdfg dffgdf dfgdfg My Text fgfdgd fdgdfg dgdfg dffgdf dfgdfg My Text fgfdgd fdgdfg dgdfg dffgdf dfgdfg");
    tv.setId(1);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);   
    ll.addView(tv, lp);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");
    LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());      
    ll.addView(myButton, lp1);
```

Comment: Ok then, How to display if multiple buttons, like in A, first row have 3 buttons adjust , second has only one and third has 2, it depend upon the size of string if adjustable or not.

Comment: Multiple button is also possible you want arrange it's properly on a layout. If you place first button in 1 row then arrange next two button on a right  of these first one and below textview                                                                                               lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,myButton.getId());
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId()); and same things for second and third row